# I am confused does the if else works differently in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, ejs

I want to know that what's wrong in this code. I am trying to implement a login code and in here I want if there is a condition will be true then only show logout either show login or signup

```
<% if(!currentUser) {%>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    <% } %>
    <% else { %>
    <li><a href="#">Signed In As : <%= currentUser.username %> </a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
<%}%>
```

This is the wrong code i figured out that instead of giving a new line to else if i make it in a single line than the code runs but that's not the case with js only i want to know what is this means if i run this code then it works

```
<% if(!currentUser) {%>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
    <li><a href="#">Signed In As : <%= currentUser.username %> </a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
<%}%>
```

Comment: it is ejs specific imo, the way it parses template tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <% } %>
> <% else { %>
> ```

is *very roughly* equivalent to:

```
}
document.write("\n    ");
else {
```

But the `else` needs to immediately follow the block after the `if (condition)`. You can't have something that writes code before it.